# C# Local heaps for threads in multithread process

Tags: c#, multithreading, heap-memory

I have a multithread process in C#, and every thread quite often tries to allocate memory from the heap. This entails in multiple heap's locks and therefore reduces advantage from threading.

Is there something like local heaps for threads, so that simultaneous attempt to allocate memory from different threads wouldn't lock one of them?

Comment: Are you sure the contention is due to the heap allocations? Interesting question by the way...

Comment: It is the most likely variant..

Comment: If you spawn a lot of thread this could be the cause by itself, independently of what they do. How many threads are running a any given time?

Comment: this problem appears even if number of threads is 5-10

Comment: I am not sure about wether its lock free across threads in single heap. However, garbage collector has a `Server` mode in which there is separate heap per processor.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx), there is no contention in a multiprocessor system when multiple threads allocate memory concurrently:

> Synchronization-free Allocations On a multiprocessor system,
>   generation 0 of the managed heap is split into multiple memory arenas
>   using one arena per thread. This allows multiple threads to make
>   allocations simultaneously so that exclusive access to the heap is not
>   required.

EDIT: Hans Passant has correctly pointed out that in order for this behavior to apply, the garbage collector must be forced to `gcServer` mode in a workstation environment. 
This is done by editing either the `app.config` or `web.config` file, and ensuring the following setting is defined:

```
<configuration> 
    <runtime> 
        <gcServer enabled="true"/> 
    </runtime> 
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: You are missing an essential part in this answer. The GC mode that does this is only enabled automatically on a server class machine. It has to be forced on on a workstation.  Document the `<gcServer>` element to clear that up.

Comment: Thank you very much Hans. I was not aware of that requirement